# How to increase MagicaVoxel size limit?

Tags: models, voxels, magicavoxel

I need to increase the size of the field you make models in by at least 20. It really doesn't make sense why you cannot go beyond 126x126x126 because in the MagicaVoxel viewer, there are sample models of 1000x1000 so there's gotta be a way to make larger models in MagicaVoxel. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, really. 126x126x126 is MV's limit. You can combine two scenes together [using MV_Import and MagicaVoxel Viewer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q45fP-fjKQM), but SLAB6 supports 256x256x255, and Paint 3D can support all the way up to 1024x1024x512. I highly recommend you check out the tutorial I linked if you want to keep using MagicaVoxel (I mean, it's free, so why the heck not), but SLAB6 and Paint 3D are your best bets if you feel like switching tools.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to complete my project this way but I found that I would have better luck with finding a different program since MagicaVoxel isn't ideal for game development. I tried SLAB6 but the interface was frustrating and the website for Paint 3D is down. I decided to go with Qubicle even though it's not free.

Comment: @Lucas Glad I could help! Yeah, SLAB6 is known for its mega confusing interface. I haven’t heard of Qubicle—hope it works out!

Answer (score 1):

If you switch to world editor (the "⇄" button) you can create multiple objects and arrange them in a bigger scene.

This was added in version 0.99 - 11/23/2017.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you export the separate boxes as objs, they all are all located in the world center. I had to align them manually in another software

Comment: Ok but the question is _"Can you increase MagicaVoxel size limit?"_ how would it be possible to do this?